# Dynamic Tables with Struts 2

Tags: jquery, struts2, freemarker

What would be the best way to create a dynamic HTML table using the JQuery plugin? What I want to do is be able to pull data from my action class and be able  to perform CRUD operations on that data which is presented in a table. I also want to be able to dynamically add rows to the table as well and have it saved server side.

I found [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-ajaxtables.html?page=1) example but it uses Dojo and I'm trying to stay away from using the Dojo Struts plugin since it is so old.

The [Struts2 JQuery Grid plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) looks like a possible solution.

Would this be a good use case to use a plugin like Freemarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I had to do something similar I used [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html). The JARs might even come with Struts2, but I don't remember. Basically, you have an object in JavaScript that looks like an object back on your server, and it handles the AJAX for you. With this approach, your JS code can look like this:

```
ObjectHandler.destroyObject(someId);
```

DWR will then make an AJAX request, calling the Java `ObjectHandler#destroyObject(int)`. Of course, you can also ask `ObjectHandler` for an array of data or whatever you like to create the table.

DWR can actually be very convenient, but the setup can take some time. (Nothing a Java Web Dev isn't use to, though. ;-))

Comment: If the OP wants to go that route the plugin looks straight forward http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/dwr-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I would just use jquery without the jquery plugin and use the struts2-json-plugin instead of DWR it provides SMD.

See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Struts2 jQuery Grid Plugin can be a good solution. It is a fast way to create a AJAX Table with CRUD Operations and you can find a lot of tutorials about.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery Gridnic. It is very easy to start with